# Работа с ресурсами assets и загрузка локального html в WebView

Tags: java, html, android

Написал простое приложение, которое читает html-файл из assets.
Файл сохранен браузером, в ассетах находится также папка с ресурсами html - с картинками.
В webView передаю url:

```
vw = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.w_view);
vw.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/mypage.html");
```

А теперь вопрос: т.к. html была сохранена браузером (мной html не правился), то в нем присутствуют ссылки на другие ресурсы, в том числе якори "Вернуться в начало" и прочее. Как сделать так, чтобы ссылки в html указывали на локальные ресурсы (переходили на локальные страницы в assets), по тапу по картинке открывалась картинка из assets, html скроллился "к началу" без загрузки ее из сети по линку в html с добавлением #top. Возможно ли вообще такое? Если нет (я почему-то так думаю), то помогите советом как сделать реализацию этого быстро и без лишних заморочек.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Варианта 2: Можно программно распарсить HTML и заменить ссылки на те что надо.
Или переопределять нажатие по ссылке:

```
this.mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
      view.loadUrl(url);
      return true;
    }
});
```

И да, этот виджет называется **W**ebView а на **V**ebView

Comment: Спасибо за исправления, опечатался. А что будет если в html переделать ссылки, к примеру, на <a href="file:///android_asset/mypage2.html">Ссыль</a>? взлетит?

Comment: Я не пробовал, но похоже что можно - http://stackoverflow.com/a/5320444/1159507